# Question about SFINAE of class template and function template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I try to specialize the template (function or class) for STL containers. The standard I used is c++14.

For the template function, I try the code as following.

```
template<typename... Args>
using int_t = int;

template<typename T, int_t
<
    typename T::value_type, //has defined the element type
    typename T::iterator, //has defined the iterator
    decltype(std::declval<T>().size()) //has defiend the "size()" function
    //other check...
> = 0>
void container_handler()
{
}
```

I think that if any type is not existed in "int_t", the template function will not be instantiated, but the compile errors are not happen when I invoke the template function as the following.

```
container_handler<int>();
```

However, I get the different result when use the class template.

```
template<typename... Args>
using int_t = int;

template<typename T , typename = int>
struct ContainerHandler;

template<typename T>
struct ContainerHandler<T, int_t
<
    typename T::value_type, //has defined the element type
    typename T::iterator, //has defined the iterator
    decltype(std::declval<T>().size()) //has defiend the "size()" function
    //other check...
>>
{
};
```

The above code works, the compile errors is occurred when I instantiates the class template with the type who hasn't defined the special type or function.

```
ContainerHandler<int> handler1; //compile error
ContainerHandler<int, int> handler2; //compile error
ContainerHandler<vector<int>> handler3; //ok
ContainerHandler<vector<int>, int> handler4; //ok
```

The "int_t" here can be replaced by "void_t" in c++17.
My question is why the SFINAE rule is different of the function template and class template.
For the function template, I try another way and it works.

```
template<typename... Args>
struct type_container
{
    using int_t = int;
};

template<typename T, typename type_container
<
    typename T::value_type, //has defined the element type
    typename T::iterator, //has defined the iterator
    decltype(std::declval<T>().size()) //has defiend the "size()" function
    //other check...
>::int_t = 0>
void container_handler()
{
}

container_handler<int>(); //compile error
container_handler<int, 0>(); //compile error
container_handler<vector<int>>(); //ok
container_handler<vector<int>, 0>(); //ok
```

I don't know what the difference between use "int_t" and "type_container::int_t".

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. It looks like everything's doing what you want it to do - what's the question?

Comment: No. I expect to get a compile error when invoke the template function "container_handler<int>();" (at the first part of the codes).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the following two lines fail is that there is no definition of `ContainerHandler` that would make the template instantiations with these template arguments successful.

```
ContainerHandler<int> handler1; //compile error
ContainerHandler<int, int> handler2; //compile error
```

If you were to provide a definition for the template, for e.g. like this:

```
template<typename T , typename = int>
struct ContainerHandler {};
```

The compilation will succeed. See [demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/VAN-nP).

EDIT:

> No. I expect to get a compile error when invoke the template function "container_handler();" (at the first part of the codes).

The `int_t` parameter of `container_handler` has a default value which is why it compiles `container_handler<int>();` 
Not having the default value will make the compilation fail.
See [demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/Kh4iy2).

Comment: Thanks for your demo. I know this, the compile error is within my expectations.